# Qual a diferença entre os elementos <img>, <picture> e <figure>?

Tags: html, html5

No HTML temos os elementos [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) (*image*), [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) e [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figura), que acredito se tratar de uma "figura" ou "imagem". O `img` é bem conhecido, os outros foram introduzidos recentemente. Noto que nos exemplos eles comumente aparecem juntos:

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="Uma imagem impressionante">   
  <figcaption>Legenda para a imagem impressionante</figcaption>
</figure>

<picture>
 <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

Qual é exatamente a função de cada um deles, e qual a forma correta de utilizá-los? Existem situações em que faria sentido combinar `figure` e `picture`, e se existem, isso é permitido?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`<img>` Elemento padrão para carregamento de imagens.

`<figure>` Elemento para ser usado em conjunto com o elemento `<figcaption>`. Sua finalidade é para marcar diagramas, ilustrações, fotos, e fragmentos de código (entre outros conteúdos).

Exemplo:

```
<figure>
  <img src="/kookaburra.jpg" alt="Kooaburra">
  <img src="/pelican.jpg" alt="Pelicano na praia">
  <img src="/lorikeet.jpg" alt="Papagaio">
  <figcaption>Pássaros Australianos. Da esquerda para direita, Kookburra, Pelicano e Papagaio. Originais por <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/rclark/">Richard Clark</a></figcaption>
</figure>
```

`<picture>` Elemento que permite tratar imagens responsivas da mesma forma que tratamos arquivos de áudio com a tag `<audio>` ou vídeos com a tag `<video>`. Também permite que você aponte várias imagens através da tag `source`.

Exemplo:

Você pode utilizar o esquema abaixo para configurar que determinada imagem seja carregada de acordo com a orientação da tela e/ou em alguma das queries declaradas.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="smaller_landscape.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="smaller_portrait.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <source srcset="default_landscape.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="default_portrait.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <img srcset="default_landscape.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

Dentro da tag `<picture>` crie a tag `<source>` para cada arquivo de imagem apontado.
Adicione a tag `media` para atribuir Queries com base na resolução de tela, orientação da tela ou densidade de pixels.
    Adicione a tag `srcset` para atribuir o caminho dos múltiplos arquivos de imagem.
    Utilize o fallback com a tag `<img>` para navegadores que não suportarem o recurso.